# SSRS - Paging Control won't enable even if there are multiple pages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have recently migrated reports from SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2014. Our web application load these reports from SSRS using URLs and reports loads perfectly fine except this weird issue with paging control (which was not an issue with 2005). As shown in below picture it shows number of pages using Global!TotalPages but for some unknown reason paging control is disabled so user cannot go to next page. PDF or EXCEL options will download entire report just fine.

[image]

If I keep pressing Refresh button then paging control will get enabled sporadically. If I use Find options then it will also enable paging control. did anyone ever had similar experience before? What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: when you scroll down the report, does it keep loading the subsequent pages as continuous pages or stop at the bottom of page one?

Comment: No it doesn't. It only shows data for the first page.

Comment: Does this behavior happen on different browsers? Edge / Chrome / I.E?

Comment: Unfortunately we are stuck in past, it is classic asp web site and it only works with IE.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with SSRS 2016.  Chrome, Edge and IE all give the same results and I can do the same hack with the find.

Answer (score 0):

Is RSCI enabled for your ReportServerTempDB ? While it should be enabled, it may be  that RXCI needs to be disabled then re-enabled.

Comment: I'm willing to try this, but the transaction isolation level is an attribute of the connection, not the database. (See [here](https://blog.sqlgrease.com/how-to-change-your-default-isolation-level-in-ssms/)). How does one set the properties of the connection between SSRS and the ReportServerTempDB?

Answer (score 0):

Check the ReportServerTempDB, you should make READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT off

Comment: I'm willing to try this, but the transaction isolation level is an attribute of the connection, not the database. (See [here](https://blog.sqlgrease.com/how-to-change-your-default-isolation-level-in-ssms/)). How does one set the properties of the connection between SSRS and the ReportServerTempDB?