# SSRS 2016 Report Not showing multi pages

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have been made aware of an issue with one of our SSRS reports.  In Dev and Test when the report is executed you get the results 1 of 2?

Dev/Test: 
[image]

And when I run the report in production I get 0 of 0.

Prod: [image]

I am using the same report parameters in each environment.

I have compared the RDL XML and the ReportServer.config from each environment and they are all the same.

The SSRS and SQL versions are all the same.  SQL 2016 SP2 CU11

Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this.

As a hack, I was able to do a find for any random word and when the result came back with nothing found then the page numbers and navigation worked as expected. :(
[image]

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? There was a similar question yesterday. It was a different version etc but page controls where disabled just like in your scenario. Might be worth following up with the author. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61330740/ssrs-paging-control-wont-enable-even-if-there-are-multiple-pages

Comment: Thanks, it does sound the same.  Hope one of us can find some direction.

Answer (score 1):

ReportServerTempDB was in RCSI mode and that was causing the issue.